# Calculating the passed time in exact years between two dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdatecomponents

This code is working well, except one thing.

If `picker.date` is `06/30/1996` (it was 18 years ago in the same day as today) the console logs the `"younger than 18"` log, but it does the same when the value of `picker.date` is `06/29/1996` which was sooner than the first date, so it was 18 years + 1 day ago. In this case it should display the second log. I know 18 is an `int` in the if statement, but that was my best idea. So i would like to log out the `"older than 18"` if  the `picker.date`'s value was formerly than 18 years ago (compared to today). Thanks in advance.

```
UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.bdDate.inputView;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

NSString *dateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:picker.date];

self.bdDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateStr];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *ageComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]

                                   components:NSYearCalendarUnit

                                   fromDate:picker.date

                                   toDate:today

                                   options:0];


if (ageComponents.year <= 18) {

    NSLog(@"younger than 18");

} else

{

    NSLog(@"older than 18");

}
```

Comment: Two dates can be on the same day and have a different time. You may be a few hours away from making that last year.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist It's not possible to calculate it based on the passed days or something? I can't imagine that there is no easy way to do it.

Comment: So if the birth date is 18 years ago to the date, aren't you 18 years old? In other words, why isn't the `if` statement `if (ageComponents.year < 18)`?

Comment: @cimp23 Short answer: no. Long answer: You don't want to deal with  things like different leap years in different calendars or [time zones](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D-5wpm-gesOY&ei=UNOxU-GiIKS_ygPYvICoBg&usg=AFQjCNE6DVexJDKjhP6pNTh0eUdJhX92kw&sig2=x3aILGi9W5WsGzMybYUaPw&bvm=bv.69837884,d.bGQ) unless absolutely necessary. It may seem simple on the surface but it's full of horrible corner cases.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Got it, it's bad news. I'm just wondering how other developers do it  in apps where age restriction is needed. I thought there must be a standard practice for this, it's a so common requirement i think.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist it seems user3386109's idea works. My first tests generated the right logs.

Comment: @user3386109 please add it as an answer and i can accept it. it's working.

Comment: OK, posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if the birth date is 18 years ago to the date, aren't you 18 years old? In other words, it seems like the `if` statement should be

```
if (ageComponents.year < 18)
```